# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/classes'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to implement this code:
https://github.com/ebagdasa/differential-privacy-vs-fairness.git

But I get this error

```
current path: saved_models/model_utk
DP: True
32
0.0001
0.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playing.py", line 282, in <module>
    helper.load_inat_data()
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/differential-privacy-vs-fairness/image_helper.py", line 223, in load_inat_data
    '/media/classes', transform=transform_train)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 316, in __init__
    is_valid_file=is_valid_file,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 145, in __init__
    classes, class_to_idx = self.find_classes(self.root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 219, in find_classes
    return find_classes(directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py", line 41, in find_classes
    classes = sorted(entry.name for entry in os.scandir(directory) if entry.is_dir())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/classes'
```

I went to the corresponding file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbKf.png)
What am I gonna do with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that I don't have any files in media/classes, but Idk which part of the code should I change to make it download to the media/classes

Comment: change the folder /media/classes to the folder where you downloaded your datasets and contain the classes